# Uploading files captured within an android application to a remote server on a desktop

Tags: php, android

I have just finished my android application which uses the native phone camera to take a picture and also record a video. I now want to use my phone to upload these items remotely on my local website(with Apache as the web-server and MySQL as the database scripting language is php). However, this website is running locally. I was hoping to create an ad-hoc. Can someone help me program my submit button on my phone with the right parameters so as to successfully upload my data on my local web application. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To upload images or videos in android generally the Multipart request is used, take a look into that.
[This link](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/) gives a basic introduction to multipart in android.

Answer (score 1):

As @Antrromet said, you have to send your files using HttpPost with [Multipart](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

This is an example of a method sending a `Bitmap` in multipart, using the [httpmime](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/dependencies.html) apache library (look at [MultipartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html)):

```
public String doHttpMultipart(String url, 
                              List<NameValuePair> pairs,
                              Bitmap bitmap,
                              String fileName) throws IOException, 
                                            ClientProtocolException,
                                            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(imageData, fileName);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = 
                    new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        reqEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);

        for(NameValuePair p : pairs) {
            reqEntity.addPart(p.getName(), new StringBody(p.getValue()));
        }

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);

        String response = "";
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            response = super.readHttpStream(response, in, httpResponse);    
        } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new IOException();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

In this method, I also send a list of parameters with my request and I read the response from the server.

On the backend, you'll receive the binary data in the [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) variable.